# spring application contexts

Tags: spring, web-applications

i have a maven project that consist of three modules .
model , cor , web .
both model and core have their own application contexts , and i want to import them in my web project . i added this part to web.xml :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext-*.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

when i deploy the project on tomcat , spring cant find any of application contexts .
i have to note that i dont get any exceptions .
but when i copy all application contextes on somewhere like WEB-INF/spring
and point contextConfigLocation to it , everything works.
what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise another thing. Use `<import ... />` in your main `applicationContext.xml` to import the two additional ones.

Comment: i tried it , but that doesn't work as well , application contexts are in two jar files core.jar and model.jar and they are in WEB-ING/lib . i wonder why container cant find them in its classpath .

Comment: @Koorosh01 I'm doing exactly the same thing and it works. So show me how exactly are you doing it

Comment: i know this is not an usual way for asking my question . but i think its better to upload my project . http://www.4shared.com/file/8LnaGN0T/parent.html thanx alot